# Sails Deployment on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, sails.js

I am having some difficulty deploying my sails.js app(v0.12) to Heroku. The application runs fine when running on the localhost, however if I access a custom a route, a 404 appears. My routes.js is as follows:

```
module.exports.routes = {
    '/': { view: 'feed' },
    'GET /ticker/:name/:userid': 'FeedController.callgraph'
};
```

my FeedController.js is:

```
module.exports = {
    subscribe: function(req, res) {
        if (!req.isSocket) {
            return res.badRequest();
        }

        sails.sockets.join(req.socket, 'feed');
        return res.ok();
    },

    callgraph: function(req, res) {
        res.send({
            start: "valid"
        });
    }
};
```

How do I make it so my routes return some data? Eg: myurl.herokuapp.com/ticker/somename/user1 returns a page?

Comment: [How to deploy your Sails.js application to Heroku](https://vort3x.me/sailsjs-heroku/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting out port:80 in production.js resolved this issue for me.